# when i put a find query in mongodb without limit and the data of total row was exceeded from 16mb an exception shows up

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a scenario where i need all document form the collection and do some calculation and show the analyze graph to the user.

At that point when I use the find function it shows me the error ( document fragment is too large: 24331229, max: 16777216  ).

in one collection document like 100000 and above.

---

**My current scenario**

I have 3 collection with 3 type of analyze representation.

1. **visit_data** (User visit the page and fill some forms having questions.)
2. **graph_data** (The graph represent the how many question answered and whats        the response of the user )
3. **tabular_data** (Its shows the question and answer of the selected questions visited by the user.)

Like google analytic graph representation of the analysis of the websites by

--> date

--> Location

--> language

--> etc.

similarly I have some filters (date,user,location) for the above type of analyze result.

So on the above collection every day 50,000 documents are interested.
If we do 7 day filter or 30 day filter at that moment the total document was >1,00,000 and the size is >16mb.

When I use **find()** function it will give me that exception.

I am using **php-mongo** to get the values.

---

Is there any other solution to do this stuff?

Please Help me.

Comment: can you provide the queries you are using? are you using aggregation queries? can you also provide a sample document that you are querying for?

Comment: In short, the maximum document size is 16MB, no workaround, no exceptions. You might want to have a deep look into the aggregation framework, which can do calculations based on the existing documents and their fields.

Comment: @kevin  I provide my current scenario, please give me a solution how to do this with mongo with a less execution time. If You have any other way then please..

Comment: You need to use allowDiskUse: true